# Android drag and drop issue with sending DragEvents

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, alpha

I integrated Drag And Drop Framework in my project. In the layout I have my own custom grid of cells that I want to be able to drag for swipe the order of them or to put 2 together in folder.

To achieve this what I did is to build custom RelativeLayout and to override the onDragEvent() callback.

Basically everything working fine, but I have issues when in the dragging process I put 2 cells into big folder .

This folder is in layout from the start of the process with GONE visibility ,and I change it visibility to VISIBLE with copy of those cells. The problem is that the RelativeLayout folder have issues with the stream of the Drag events. The stream is stop sometimes and continue just if I stop the movement for some time.

I think of moving all the dragging logic to the parent so just 1 view will get all the event but I really prefer to find solution and stay with my logic because it taking advantage the framework data about which View is currently below the Dragging view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries and research I found out that the Drag And Drop Framework stops to send most of the DragEvents when the alpha prperty of the View is different from 1.